# Синхронизация данных из MySQL в Oracle

Tags: oracle, mysql

Каким образом можно втянуть бэкап базы данных MySQL в Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Если бэкап уже сделан (с дефолтными опциями), то там много чего придётся вычищать. Проще заново залить его в MySQL и вытаскивать уже правильным способом.

**Путь 1** (если данных не очень много и migration надо сделать 1 раз):

1. mysqldump --skip-opt --compatible=oracle .. > backup.sql
2. заменить varchar -> varchar2 и возможно ещё что-то по мелочи
3. залить в Oracle, скормив sqlplus'у

**Путь 2** (если данных много и/или операцию придётся повторять многократно, т.е. нужна автоматизация):

1) Отдельно и вдумчиво перенести схему данных (в Oracle нет AUTO_INCREMENT, но есть SEQUENCES и т.д.)

2) Из MySQL сохранить данные табличек в CSV (каждую отдельно). Примерно так:

```
SELECT col1, col2, .. INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.text'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM mytable;
```

3) Загрузить в Oracle SQLLDR'ом

**Путь 3** (для фанатов BI)

Использовать BI Tool (Pentaho / TalenD / etc.)